# python selenium find element by xcode

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
print("This program finds the imdb rating of a movie or TV series!!!")
def get_results(search_term):
    url="https://www.google.com"
    browser=webdriver.Safari()
    browser.get(url)
    search_box= browser.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    href=""
    links=browser.get_element_by_class("//slp f//a")
    print(links)

    browser.close()

search_key=input("Enter the movie name : ")
get_results("what is the imdb rating of "+search_key)
```

How can I print a specific line from a webpage to the terminal?
Can I use `find_element_by_xcode()` or `get_element_by_class()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS Selector`, `xPath` etc. For example you have this search [results](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=VfcnW8iAH8WWsAHqq72IAQ&q=what%20is%20the%20imdb%20rating%20of%20lost&oq=what%20is%20the%20imdb%20rating%20of%20lost&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1.8668.10704.0.13023.8.6.0.0.0.0.365.811.0j4j0j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.6.1037.6..0j35i39k1j0i22i30k1.226.pTCadN-KCd0) and you want to print the rating:

[image]

Then you can locate the element like this:

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'slp f']/text()") # find all elements with given selector
for link in links
   print(link) # prints in the terminal current link value
               # for example ' Rating: 8,4/10 - ‎432,408 votes'
```

More information how to locate elements with `Python` you will get in the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

I got this error after updating this program, I've tried putting #div instead of div but I got the same results

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look. The problem is, that on the result page there are many same elements. So you can locate all of them and then print also all of them or choose which rating do you need.

Comment: the browser abruptly got closed even before executing the loop

Comment: Updated my answer, please have a look

Comment: Still doing the same, does everything before the loop and then closes the browser and terminates the program.

Comment: Try to determine the length of links like this: `len(links)` before loop